# Unable to connect to server with ssh2_connect

Tags: php, ssh, network-programming

I'm using the following commands:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('IP_ADDRESS', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass');
echo ssh2_exec($connection, 'ls');
```

And I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-5): Unable to exchange encryption keys
```

On the remote server I see the following:

```
Unable to negotiate with IP_ADDRESS port xxx: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
```

I can't really figure out what the problem is. This is the first time I'm trying to use ssh2_connect to connect to a remote server.

Comment: Sounds like the remote server might not support passwords? I know my servers don’t.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The server supports passwords. I can connect manually..